# Running client and server on same machine

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, network-programming, winsock

I have both a client and server application using UDP port 25565.
In order to run these on the same machine, because only one application may bind itself to port 25565, does this mean that it is necessary for me to use two separate ports for transmitting data between the applications?

What I have in mind is the following -

Client -> 25565 -> Server

Client <- 25566 <- Server

Is this the only solution or is there another way of handling this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Your server application open a port and wait for client to connect.
- Client need to know this port in advance so it can establish a connection to the desired service.
- Client can use any available ports to initiate this connection (better to use ports > 1000).
- The server sees in the incomming packet wich port the client is using, so it will send anwser to it. No need to specify it in your design.
- After handshake the TCP/IP connection is then identified by these 4 values : server IP, server port, client IP, client port.
- No other connection could have the same four values.

To answer your question. A TCP/IP connection is bi-directional, once established, the server can send data to the client and the other way around.

I would draw the scheme like this :

SERVER port 25565 <-> CLIENT port 25566 (or any other port)

Comment: I'm not using TCP, I'm using UDP.

Comment: I guess you know UDP is not secure, you can loose packets, they can arrive in wrong order, you can't pass gateway from server to client and everything... But both server and client are on same machine so. Using UDP your client can open any port to listen and tell the server to send there. And your scheme is right for UDP.

Comment: Yes I know it's not secure but it shouldn't be a problem for my goals. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, no. Only the server needs to listen on the port 25565 - the client will just connect to that port. There is no reason to specify which client the port should 'use' to connect to that port. Also, once the server has accepted the connection, the port can listen for other requests.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using UDP sockets.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of separate UDP ports is to eliminate conflicts among applications listening to incoming packets. Changing one of these ports is probably the best solution.

However, if you really want both programs to listen on the same port you will need to use virtual network interfaces such as TUN/TAP (there is a [Windows port](http://www.varsanofiev.com/inside/using_tuntap_under_windows.htm)). Then both applications will bind to the port with tha same number but on the different network interfaces.